# Retrieve many values with ajax from get in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Here I have 3 file ajax.js, index.php, and retrieve.php.

```
$('#button').click(function(){
   var string=$('#string').val();
   $.get('php/retrieve.php',{input: string} ,function(data){ 
       $('#feedback').text(data);                           
   }); 
});
```

index.php

```
<html lang="fr">
<head><title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>


    <input id="string" type="text" name="string"/><input id="button" type="button" value="Go"/>
    <input id="string2" type="text" name="string"/><input id="button2" type="button" value="Go"/>
    <div id="feedback"></div>
    <div id="feedback2"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

retrieve.php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['input'])){
        $string=$_GET['input'];
        echo strrev($string);
    }
?>
```

In retrieve.php, I retrieve the input value from ajax.js. ajax.js retrieve the value from index.php. But here it only
retrieves one value (from `<input id="string" type="text" name="string"/>`)
I want to retrieve many values from index.php (for example `<input id="button2" type="button" value="Go"/>`)
How can I do that ?

Comment: You're missing your `<form>` tags. Your inputs have the same name. You may want to [review jQuery AJAX basics](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html). What do you mean by "retrieve many values"? At the same time? On separate button clicks?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a more generic jQuery function that will work in both cases. First, let's correct your HTML to include proper form tags and proper naming of the inputs:

```
<html lang="fr">
<head><title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="myForm" action="retrieve.php">
        <input id="string" type="text" name="string1"/>
        <input id="button" type="button" value="Go"/>
        <input id="string2" type="text" name="string2"/>
        <input id="button2" type="button" value="Go"/>
    </form>
    <div id="feedback"></div>
    <div id="feedback2"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now you can use one function to handle either button click:

```
$('[type="button"]').click(function(){
   var currentinput = $(this).prev('input').attr('name'); // string1 or string 2
   var string = $(this).prev('input').val();
   $.get('php/retrieve.php',{input: string} ,function(data){
       if('string1' == currentInput) {
           $('#feedback').text(data);
       } else {
           $('#feedback2').text(data);
       }                           
   }); 
});
```

You will likely want to only have one button per form, so you should really separate the forms, each with their own inputs. Even so, the above jQuery will work and you can add more, similar, forms at a later date should you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON notation for your response, it is an beautiful way to represent data

On the PHP side you use [json_encode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to encode an object to JSON

On the javascript side you use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to decode

This way you can:

1. add multiple values to an array or object on the server side in PHP
2. encode said object
3. decode it client side with the ajax response

   ```
   $.get('php/retrieve.php',{input: string} ,function(data){ 
       var response = JSON.parse(data);
   }
   ```

---

To retrieve multiple input's I suggest combining them in a `Form`:

first embed your inputs in an form with a submit button, you should also not use the same `name` twice because it won't work now, create unique names

```
<form action="GET" id="myForm">
  <input id="string" type="text" name="string" />
  <input id="button" type="button" value="Go" />
  <input id="string2" type="text" name="string" />
  <input id="button2" type="button" value="Go" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

and write code to submit the ajax way

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(event) {


  // Stop form from submitting normally
  event.preventDefault();

  var $form = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "retrieve.php",
    data: $form.serialize(),
    success: function() {
      console.log("it worked");
    }
  });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c3mhjozc/1/

Comment: Why change to AJAX? What advantage does it provide over `$.get()`? Why add a submit button when the OP wants to use the existing buttons?

Comment: @JayBlanchard That's just a shorthand notation, no real advantage besides for readability in an example, but feel free to use `#.get('retrieve.php', $form.serialize(), function() {
      console.log("it worked");
    })`

Comment: I know that it is [shorthand](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html), I was just wondering why you changed to that and added a submit button.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I changed it for easy readability and I added a submit button in order to show the regular way of submitting form and at the same time show how to do it without the page reloading

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').click(function(){
var string=$('#string').val();
   $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: "php/retrieve.php?input=" + string,
      dataType: "html"
   }).done(function(data){
      $('#feedback').html(data);
   });
});
```

Perform a GET request in retrieve.php and supply the url with a variable input with the value of the string. The retrieved data will then be reflected on `#feedback` div.

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: The OP *is* doing an AJAX request in the form of a `$.get()`.