# How to send multiple variables through ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The code below sends the id of item to more.php to load more content. It works fine. Now to add some more features I need to send one more id to more.php through the same code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click','.show_more',function(){
var ID = $(this).attr('id');
$('.show_more').hide();
$('.loding').show();
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'more.php',
  data:'id='+ID,
  success:function(html){
    $('#show_more_main'+ID).remove();
    $('.display').append(html);
  }
  });    
 });
});
</script>
```

Suppose second id is `var catid = '<?php echo $cat ?>';` how to send this `catid` through the same ajax code. `data : {id : id, catid : catid}` is something I should do but can't get how to deal in current situation when my data carries `data:'id='+ID,`.

Comment: This should work. use it as `{id:ID}`

Comment: user `data: { id:ID, userid: userid }`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546635/retrieve-many-values-with-ajax-from-get-in-php/34546662#34546662

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your should look like. specify your data as an object:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.show_more', function () {
            var ID = $(this).attr('id');
            $('.show_more').hide();
            $('.loding').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'more.php',
                data: { id:ID, userid: userid },
                success: function (html) {
                    $('#show_more_main' + ID).remove();
                    $('.display').append(html);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve multiple input's I suggest combining them in a Form:

first embed your inputs in an form with a submit button, you should also not use the same name twice because it won't work now, create unique names

```
<form action="GET" id="myForm">
    <input id="string" type="text" name="string" />
    <input id="string2" type="text" name="string" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

and write code to submit the ajax way

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(event) {
    // Stop form from submitting normally
   event.preventDefault();

   var $form = $(this);

 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "retrieve.php",
     data: $form.serialize(), //make it JSON
     success: function() {
     console.log("it worked");
     }
    });
});
```